# How to access Magento DB phpmyadmin

Tags: magento-1.9, database

how can I access the Magento DB with phpMyAdmin?

I'm learning programming and wrote everything on a local version of `Magento 1.9.2.4`, on the local version I entered localhost and could see the DB in phpMyAdmin.

Now the company im doing an apprenticeship at gave me a URL for the Magento Backend and the information to access the FTP server, but how do I open the DB?
/app/etc/local.xml says `<connection> <host>localhost</host>`.

What do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for localhost, I use port 8080 localhost:8080. you will need credentials as well to sign in to the database... so ask them PHPMyAdmin port (if they use PHPMyAdmin at all) user and password. If they don't use PHPMyAdmin you have to log on staging server and check data in tables manually in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Add /phpmyadmin/ after.

like: yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Storm also for connect to your database.

It had many helpful feature.

[image]